# How to hide/delete the symbol pin types (named as pas/sup) from the eagle schematics?

Tags: components, schematics, eaglecad, cad

[image]

Hi there,

I was trying to do something and not sure what I did without knowingly those small green circles along with names has appeared on ever pin of all the components I had in the schematics.

Could you please let me know how to hide/delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run the following command in the schematic window:

```
display -pins
```

If you want to view them again:

```
display pins
```

---

As is the way with Eagle, you can also do it from the toolbar. Simply click on the visible layers/display button, find layer 93 (`Pins`) and hide it by clicking the number so it is no longer blue. Then click OK.

[image: Hide Pins Layer]

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. Thought I messed up with the net label settings.And I was trying to find that command in the Eagle doc but your reply saved time.

Comment: Oh yeah now I got it. Probably I might have disabled it unknowingly. Good find.

Comment: This also hides the green circles, which are pretty nifty to be able to see, as well as the labels.